# Prove that the solution of the Cauchy problem for $x''(t) + (1+c^2)x(t) - 2c^2x(t)^3 = 0$ is periodic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Consider the Cauchy problem $$x''(t) + (1+c^2)x(t) - 2c^2x(t)^3 = 0$$ with $c \in [0,1]$ and the conditions $$ x(0)=0, \, x'(0) = 1$$ Prove that for every $c \in [0,1)$ the solution is a periodic function.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply with $2x'$ and integrate to get a first integral
$$
V(x,x')=x'^2+(1+c^2)x^2-c^2x^4.
$$
Solutions of the ODE follow the level curves of this first integral. If you can show that the level curve for the given initial condition is bounded, the solution must be periodic.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But can I ask why  if the level curve is bounded than the solution is periodic?

Comment: Because you know the stationary points $(x,x')=(0,0)$ and $(\pm\sqrt{(1+c^{-2})/2},0)$. Outside these the solution never stops moving, it always moves forward along a level curve. And if that is bounded, it is closed, the end is the beginning and the motion is periodic.